# All-round 100% portable terminal color support check

Tags: shell-script, terminal, colors, portability, tput

### Test for terminal color support using `tput`

```
#!/bin/sh
colors_supported()
{
    command -v tput > /dev/null 2>&1 && tput setaf 1 > /dev/null 2>&1
}
```

---

I am currently using this code to establish if `tput` terminal colors are supported.

It seems to work well, the question is: Is this piece of code POSIX-ly 100% portable and usable on all kinds of Unix-based systems? I mean Linux, *BSD, etc.

---

I ask because I can't try it out everywhere at this moment.

---

Which colors:

```
tput setaf 1
tput setaf 2
tput setaf 3
tput setaf 4
tput setaf 5
tput setaf 6
tput setaf 7
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### TL;DR

The suggested check will fail to work on some kinds of Unix systems.

### Long answer

- POSIX doesn't cover this aspect of **`tput`**, but read the [**Portability**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html#h2-PORTABILITY) section of the manual page.
- Most systems do use terminfo names (such as `setaf`).
- FreeBSD for instance (although the underlying library is `ncurses`) provides a **`tput`** that only supports `termcap` names. The FreeBSD [manual page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tput&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD%2011.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html) is not clear, but see the [source-code](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/usr.bin/tput/tput.c?revision=326025&view=markup#l111), which uses [**`tgetstr`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_termcap.3x.html#h3-CAPABILITY-VALUES) (`termcap`) rather than [**`tigetstr`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_terminfo.3x.html#h3-Terminal-Capability-Functions) (`terminfo`).
- the [`terminfo`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-Predefined-Capabilities) manual page lists the `terminfo` and `termcap` names, e.g., `setaf` and `AF`. You could try using both in succession since the [exit code](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html#h2-EXIT-CODES) tells whether the capability is defined.

  For example, you could modify your test function to handle either case this way:

  ```
  colors_supported()
  {
      command -v tput > /dev/null 2>&1 && ( tput setaf || tput AF ) > /dev/null 2>&1
  }
  ```